# Sails.js, API executing without route configuration and controller.method

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, sails.js

Hey guys here I have a peculiar situation in Sails.js

- I created new model and controller named "sponsor" using `sails generate api sponsor` in the cmd-line
- Then I created the **route:** `post /create/new/sponsor' : 'SponsorController.create` ,created a method "**create**" inside the controller and structured the respective model.
- Now when am trying it out in postman using legit configuration, everything is working fine, as its is supposed to work. New sponsor is getting created!!

  > **THE PROBLEM IS :**
  >
  > - Even when Iam passing URL `localhost:port/sponsor` new sponsor is getting created  (which is supposed to throw **status:404**) as there is no such route defined.
  > - Then I deleted the controller method "**create**" and tried using the url `localhost:port/sponsor`, strange it still works!!!!
  > - The only ERROR that I got is in cmd-prompt saying "**Invalid usage of publishCreate():: Values must have an 'id' instead ...** (the body passed )"

I checked with the other other APIs that I have created before, everything is working normally according to routes defined ie.  if [ url doesnt match route == status:404 ]

I want to know why is it happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Sails.js has `blueprints` enabled by default. This automatically creates `GET, PUT, POST, Delete` routes for your controllers at the url `localhost:port/sponsor`

See [Concepts](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/blueprints) & [Reference](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api) for more information.

It is possible to turn off blueprints in sails.js `config/blueprints.js`, uncomment `actions` and set it's value to `false`

`actions: false,`

Also the index "**rest:**" of `config/blueprints.js` needs to be uncommented and set to false to disable the self generated routes ie `localhost:port/sponsor`

`rest: false,`

Thank you 
@Callum

for pointing out the solution

> It's important to realize that, even if you haven't defined these yourself, as long as. A model exists with the same name as the controller, Sails will respond with built-in CRUD. logic in the form of a JSON API, including support for sort, pagination, and filtering.

Best Callum

Comment: I uncommented and action:false and still localhost:port/sponsor is working

Comment: And also I want to know why the other APIs are not affected ? They are not behaving the way this "Sponsor" is behaving

Comment: I found the solution and edited your answer @Callum please review, for it will help others with similar problem. Thanks once again for pointing out the solution

Comment: Glad you managed to get this sorted! My bad on overlooking the "rest" property